# Make other components aware of @WebIntegrationTest random port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-annotations

I've been playing around with Spring boot these last days, and I really like the @WebIntegrationTest annotation, that allows to startup a Tomcat and deploy a Spring boot app in it automatically. It gives the option of starting Tomcat on a random port, which is very easy if you are testing a webapp. But my case is slightly different. Whole source code is available here :

https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/spring-projects

Using Spring Batch, I need to parse an Excel file, and write the items to a REST webService. It works well when I know in advance the URL that the writer needs to use, and I am able to test the whole flow in a few seconds using Spring Boot, by loading a "hollow" @RestController that receives the requests and makes them available to the test for assertions.

(Note : I'm sure this only would be pretty useful to quite a lot of people. it would work also if you're trying to test a Spring Integration config)

It's the batch that I want to test, not the webService. But to test the output of this batch, I need this "hollow" webservice.

```java
     @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
     @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = 
     {
      //the webservice client that the batch should use (planning for SOAP impl later)
      RestCustomerWsClient.class,
      //the "target" web server, with the 'hollow' endpoint listening
      TargetRESTSystem.class,
      //the application under test and its config
      TestSpecificConfiguration.class,
      CustomerBatchConfiguration.class}
                                )
    @WebIntegrationTest("server.port:8080")
    @IntegrationTest({"spring.batch.job.enabled=false"})
    public class CustomerBatchWithRestTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}") 
    public int targetWebServerPort;


    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private DummyCustomerController endpoint ;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext  appCtx ;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;


    @Before
    public void loadDynamicProperty() {

        EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment(appCtx, "target.port:"+targetWebServerPort);

        assertThat(env.getProperty("target.port")).isEqualTo(String.valueOf(targetWebServerPort)).as("port for target server is not register correctly in properties");
    }




    @Test
    public void targetShouldReceiveExpectedCustomer() throws Exception {


        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        //assertThat(jobExecution.getStatus()).isEqualTo(BatchStatus.COMPLETED);
        assertThat(endpoint.getReceivedCustomers()).hasSize(1);

        Customer actualCustomer=endpoint.getReceivedCustomers().get(0);
        assertThat(actualCustomer.getId()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(actualCustomer.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Vincent");
        assertThat(actualCustomer.getLastName()).isEqualTo("FUCHS");
    }

}
```

With these annotations, TargetRESTSystem will be deployed in a tomcat on port 8080.

On the batch side, the component that writes is configured like this, with a property file giving target.port=8080 :

```java
public class RestCustomerWsClient implements CustomerWsClient {

    @Value("${target.host}")
    private String targetHost="undefined";

    @Value("${target.port}")
    private String targetPort="undefined";

    @Override
    public void sendCustomer(Customer customerFromExcel) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.postForEntity("http://"+targetHost+":"+targetPort+"/integrate", customerFromExcel, null);

        System.out.println("sent client integration request");
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works well because I defined myself the port and made the value match between WebIntegrationTest annotation and the property file on the batch side.

But what if I want to make my test more robust and use a random port, because I don't want it to fail if 8080 is already used by another process ? I can use this instead :

```
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort=true)
```

I've tried various things, but none is working because of the order in which things get loaded :

- the @Before method to put the dynamic value in properties, but I need to refresh context after, and Spring won't allow me
- I also tried with tweaking ApplicationContextInitializer / AbstractGenericContextLoader, but at the time they are called, Tomcat hasn't started yet, and I don't have the random value yet.

So basically, I would need my test to startup Tomcat, maybe deploy my hollow webservice in it, give me the random port so that I can add it in context, and **then only** load my TestSpecificConfiguration / CustomerBatchConfiguration.

Any idea if this is possible ? or is the WebIntegrationTest annotation really targetted at testing webapps, on which we perform ourselves http requests within the test ?

Thanks

Vincent

===== EDIT

in the latest version of the code I have committed, I'm using reflection to set the dynamic port on my component that is already loaded in Spring context. 
https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/spring-projects/commit/df7bf3a76fc6109fdacac21d7dd10b045ccd0458

It works, but obviously it's not the best solution. So if anbody has a clean way of doing this, that would be great !